# using closest().find().text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i previously asked a question and got a good solution. here is the question:

[jquery: how to find an element which is coming 2 elements before current element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536892/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-which-is-comming-2-elements-before-current-element)

when im using the solution which i got :

```
paragrafheading.push($(this).closest('> h3').find('> h3').text());
```

im getting only [object Object] instead of the element text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that because it's not finding your `<h3>` correctly, so there's nothing to call `.text()` on, so you're pushing an empty set of jQuery elements.  I would use this to find the `<h3>` instead:

```
$(this).closest('p').prev('h3').text();
```

Not sure what the previous answer was after, but this is a bit cleaner and, more importantly, works :)